# Scan for open ports on subdomain

Tags: nmap, ports, sub-domain

I am curently scanning for open ports on a subdomain. Say I have `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com`, but this subdomain can only be reached at port 8443. How can I scan for other potential open ports? Nmap will show this warning when trying to run a scan, even with host discovery disabled

> No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Security.SE! We would need additional information, especially the command you tried to use. From what I understand, you did not specify what host to scan, so nmap did not scan any.

Comment: I've used nmap -v -A  -Pn sub.web.xyz . Same command without the subdomain works.

Comment: nmap -sT -T4 subdomain.example.com

Comment: It turns out I was just looking at the problem the wrong way.
Specifying the port range to scan for did the trick: nmap -v -A -Pn -p 1-10000 subdomain.example.com